# Edge First Tab Error when Opening via System()

Tags: c++, google-chrome, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-edge, chromium

When doing

```cpp
const std::string LaunchStr = "C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe --profile-directory=\"Profile 1\" C:\\Users\\redacted1\\redacted4.html";
System(LaunchStr.c_str());
```

Microsoft Edge launches as expected, the loaded profile is the correct one and there is a new tab on `redacted4.html`. However, the first tab (and the focused one too) is the following url `program%20--fast-start%20files%20%28x86%29/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe`. Which I find weird because nowhere in my code do I write `program%20--fast-start%20files%20%28x86%29/`.

Why is that? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11? If yes then better use raw string literals: `R"(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1" C:\Users\redacted1\redacted4.html)"` and try again

Comment: I can see that you are using the double quotes in between the path. Try to pass the whole path in double-quotes and do not use the double quotes in your path. See whether it works or not.

Comment: @Gerard, does your issue get solved using the code sample provided in the answer? if yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try to refer to the sample code below that may help you to launch the MS Edge browser correctly with the correct profile and with the specified URL.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = { sizeof sei };
    sei.lpVerb = L"open";
    sei.lpFile = L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe";
    sei.lpParameters = L"--user-data-dir=\"C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data\\Profile 1\" C:\\Users\\redacted1\\redacted4.html"; // Modify the path for user-profile here...
    ShellExecuteExW(&sei);
}
```

Note: You can type `edge://version/` in the address bar of the Edge browser and see the profile path to modify it in the above code sample.

Output:

[image]